# How to filter JSON string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

Suppose I have a JSON string as given below

```
var data =[{"Id":140,"Title":"My brochure","BrochurDate":"\/Date(1408473000000)\/","Date":"Wednesday, August 20, 2014","Categories":[{"Name":"Seniors","Id":127},{"Name":"Legislation","Id":129}]},{"Id":129,"Title":"Brochure 2","BrochurDate":"\/Date(1407436200000)\/","Date":"Friday, August 08, 2014","Categories":[{"Name":"Kids","Id":123},{"Name":"Insurance","Id":128}]},{"Id":128,"Title":"Brochure 1","BrochurDate":"\/Date(1402165800000)\/","Date":"Sunday, June 08, 2014","Categories":[]}]
```

How can I filter the above JSON data by 1. **Categories** 2. **BrochurDate**
between a start date and end date?

Suppose I have a design as shown in below image
[image]

Here is the **jsfiddle**[2](http://jsfiddle.net/wLaxu1xL/1/) that i have tried, It works fine for **Title** but am not able to find result by categories,see the commented line there

Comment: There's a function for that - funnily enough it's called `filter` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I heard that has browser compatibility issue,do you @Alnitak know how to use jQuery.grep() instead of that

Comment: Sure, but there's a trivial shim for that on the page I linked to.  My mantra is "code to modern standards, shim for old browsers".

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each( data,function(index,value)
{
  console.log(ind+' '+value);
});
```